# Continue script after reboot with crontab in a terminal

Tags: bash, shell, cron, root

I have a bash script to install some stuff in linux. The install script needs to be run as root. The installation process reboots twice and continues after each reboot.

I managed to manipulate the crontab to add/remove jobs to get that working. However, I would like the user to be informed if the install script has finished or not, so he/she can wait until the last reboot has finished.

The only solution I could think of was to run the crontab job in an open terminal, so the user can see the installation is still in progress.

**Question 1**: Is this a good solution? Any alternative?

**Question 2**: If the solution is good, how can I make sure a terminal is opened and the crontab job is run in that terminal?

Comment: How would the user like to be "informed"? Text message, GUI popup, message in a terminal? Is the system booted to multiuser while the installation continues? Is the X server running while the installation continues? Is the user who needs to be informed sitting at the console, or remote?

Comment: Requiring a reboot - let alone two! - seems very un-Unixy. Are you really sure there is no way to avoid at least one reboot? Which problem are you actually trying to solve with this? (Replacing a somehow compromised kernel with a generic one, then installing a less generic one to replace it is pretty much the only scenario I can imagine where this would even remotely make sense. Except it really doesn't.)

Comment: @tripleee I'm installing software on a raspberry. I first do an upgrade/update of the os. The  I install golang. Then I install the software using go install ./...
Can this be done without rebooting?

Comment: @MFnx that absolutely will not require any reboots, it's classical, at worst you'll need to reload your terminal environment.

Comment: @GaryO I justed wanted to keep it simple and send a message in the terminal. Therefore I wanted to run the crontab jobs in the terminal. The user sits at the console. The jobs are added to the crontab of the root user.

Comment: @Redda.Drissi ok, I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: If you upgrade the kernel, that's ultimately going to require a reboot. But leaving that to the installing user to do manually at a convenient time is a well-proven standard solution. Maybe display a message to that effect at the end of the installation. None of this makes sense to run from `cron`.

Comment: @triplee Ok, I removed those jobs from cron and just reload my bashrc when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are executed without any attached terminal. You'll have to create one in your cron script, and redirect all output from your script's commands to it. Maybe the simplest option is to redirect your script's output to a logfile, and open a terminal which just does `tail -f <logfile>`. You can then kill the terminal when your script is complete. If you're using xterm (as an example), you can do `xterm -e "tail -f logfile.txt"`.

Comment: Or simply not try to use `cron` for something which is clearly not a recurring scheduled job. Just run the thing in a terminal instead.

Comment: Of course, cron is not needed here. If you want to run something only once on reboot you can also add it to /etc/init.d (and symlink into the appropriate runlevel), and delete it once it's been run. But in either case, the OP wants the process to be visible to the user.